# Migrate WordPress data to Docker Container?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm working on migrating a WordPress data to Docker container.
I followed this tutorial here:
hub.docker.com/r/aveltens/wordpress-backup/
Now I'm running WP on instance Amazon EC 2 with IP address 52.193.x.x
But In step 2 of Migrate your blog to Docker they said that i need to have fresh install on localhost:8080 . What should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were worried about how to access that your browser, then your address would be `http://52.193.x.x:8080` if you have the 8080 open for you in EC2. Just a note from the instructions that you should do a restoration in step3 before doing that.

If this is not your problem, please explain here what your problem is :)

Comment: Ah thank you, it worked! So i have a question, what is the meaning of migrating WP to docker container? To deploy and replace WP's data or sth? In case i want to use docker to move all data of wordpress, how should i do?

Comment: Worked: Can you please mark that as answer in that case. To be open, the blog was written by [someone](https://hub.docker.com/u/aveltens/) whom I presume is a random user (not belonging to Docker.io etc.). So I cannot comment much on that. However, I can try answering your questions based on my own opinions. One approach to do data migration is by using docker's [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/). So you have the data as it is on your host and mount it to your containers or make the data as a data container and re-use it across docker containers